# Rectangle shape fill picture which exist in worksheet in vba

Tags: excel, vba, image, shapes

I already have a picture in worksheet, and i have rectangle shape.
Now i want to fill that picture into the rectangle shape by vba code.

```
Dim img As Picture
    
Set img = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Pictures("Pic01").Copy
shape1.Fill.UserPicture (img)
```

After run that code, the shape1 does not fill. (if i change the img object to one picture file path then the shape1 filled).

=> How to fill picture to the shape1 without picture file path?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be no direct way through VBA to fill a shape with an image from the clipboard (This could possibly be accomplished using Windows API.). However, a VBA workaround solution is possible.

```vb
Sub FillShapeWithImage()
    Dim strPath As String, strFname As String
    Dim objShp As Shape, objImg As Shape
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    Set objImg = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Pic01")
    Set objShp = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 14")
    strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    objImg.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
    strFname = strPath & "\" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmddhhmmss") & ".png"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, objShp.Width, objShp.Height).Chart
        .Parent.Select
        .Paste
        .Export strFname, "png"
        .Parent.Delete
    End With
    objShp.Fill.UserPicture strFname
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill strFname
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

> **Question**:the picture size (200, 400), but the shape size (200,800), so how to adjust the picture fit full the shape size? o

> **Answer**: You can get shape autofitting code in

[In Excel, can a button be created to insert photos into cells without distorting the original image aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76864383)

---

> Question: how to rotate the picture before save png file?

> Answer: Roate a shape with `ShapeRange.IncrementRotation`. Please refers to Microsoft document.

> [Shape.IncrementRotation method (Excel)](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.incrementrotation?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

**Note**: Rotating a shape **doesn't** modify its Width/Height properties, which can be confusing. Use caution when auto-fitting a rotated shape.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim shp
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("C:\Temp\test.png")
    Debug.Print shp.Width, shp.Height
    shp.ShapeRange.IncrementRotation 90
    ' output is same as above
    Debug.Print shp.Width, shp.Height
End Sub
```

Comment: please help me, the picture size (200, 400), but the shape size (200,800),
so how to adjust the picture fit full the shape size?
Thank you so much!

Comment: It is helpful for you.  `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76864383`

Comment: Thank you Taller_ExcelHome,
can you teach me how to rotate the picture before save png file?

Comment: I hvae updated my post to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you Taller_ExcelHome,
It working good.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the UserPicture method only accepts a string (path to an image file - URL or local drive), and there doesn't seem to be an immediately obvious way around this. As an alternative, you could always treat the Picture object as a Shape object, and then adjust its properties to match that of the destination shape.

```
Sub ReplicateShape()
    Dim PictureShape As Shape
    Dim SourceShape As Shape
    Set PictureShape = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Picture1")
    Set SourceShape = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Shape 1")
    With PictureShape
        .Height = SourceShape.Height
        .Width = SourceShape.Width
        .AutoShapeType = SourceShape.AutoShapeType
    End With
End Sub
```

The above assumes that there is a Picture1 and a "Shape 1" on Sheet1 of the Workbook containing the VBA code. The code could be adjusted (if required) to first create a duplicate of the Picture object and then adjust the shape of the copy.