# How to control both width AND height of an inserted object in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

The VBA code below is used to insert a logo image within a certain space in my worksheet. The issue I am having is, I can't seem to set a maximum width AND height for the inserted object. It either sets a maximum height, OR a maximum width, whichever bit of code is written last.. Can I not control both? As different logos will be different sizes, some wider, some taller..

This is the code I am using currently:

```vb
    Sub Add_logo()

    Dim fNameAndPath As Variant
    Dim img As Picture
    fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select picture to be imported")
    If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
    Set img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fNameAndPath)

    With img
    .Name = "Logo"
    .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("y11").Left
    .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("y11").Top
    .Width = ActiveSheet.Range("Y11:AL11").Width
    .Height = ActiveSheet.Range("Y11:Y13").Height
    .PrintObject = True
    End With
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Inserted pictures default `LockAspectRatio=msoTrue`. Change in VBA before adjusting height/width independently.

```
    With img
    ' Set to False to allow independently adjusting Width and Height
    .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    .Name = "Logo"
    .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("y11").Left
    .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("y11").Top
    .Width = ActiveSheet.Range("Y11:AL11").Width
    .Height = ActiveSheet.Range("Y11:Y13").Height
    .PrintObject = True
    End With
```

Please refers to below to avoid the distorted image.

[In Excel, can a button be created to insert photos into cells without distorting the original image aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76864383/in-excel-can-a-button-be-created-to-insert-photos-into-cells-without-distorting)

Comment: You have to use  `.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse` as `img` is a picture object - which doesn't have the property `LockAspectRatio`-

Comment: @dan parsloe: you should be aware that by this the logo might get distorted!