# Excel VBA: Transferring user-selected images from a userform to a worksheet with conserved aspect ratio and responsive fit

Tags: excel, vba, image, userform

I am creating a userform in Excel using VBA that accepts user-selected images. When the user submits the form with a chosen image, the userform is meant to put the image into column A of the connected worksheet, so that the aspect ratio of the image is maintained and the image and cell fit together, like a picture and picture frame.

I tried the below code:

```
Dim EmptyRow As Long

'Make the Appointments worksheet active
Worksheets("Appointments").Activate

'Determine the empty row
EmptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B:B")) + 1

'Insert and format photo
Set photo = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(ImagePath)
With photo

    .Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(EmptyRow, 1).Left
    .Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(EmptyRow, 1).Top
    
    With .ShapeRange
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Width = ActiveSheet.Columns("A").ColumnWidth
    End With
    
    'Set the format of the picture cell
    ActiveSheet.Rows(EmptyRow).RowHeight = photo.ShapeRange.Height
    
    .Placement = 1
    
End With
```

At insertion, image width is not set to the width of the cell they are in. When adjusting image/cell dimensions, image aspect ratio isn't maintained and image/cell width/height does not change to fit the cell/image.

At insertion, I was expecting the cell containing the image to act as a picture frame for the image. In other words, I was expecting

1. the image's aspect ratio to be conserved,
2. the image width to equal the width of the column containing it,
3. and the height of the row containing it to equal the image height.

Upon changing image/cell dimensions, I was expecting the dimensions of the cell/image to change such that

1. the image's/cell's aspect ratio to be maintained,
2. and the dimensions of the image/cell to fit with the change.

Edit: With taller_ExcelHome's suggestion, the inserted image now has preserved aspect ratio. It equates its width to the width of the picture column, lengthens its height according to its aspect ratio, and equates the height of the row containing it to the image's height. Widening the picture column also widens the image correctly. However, it break the aspect ratio of the image instead of lengthening the height of the image and row accordingly:

[image: Stretching column width doesn't stretch image height and row height to preserve aspect ratio]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost complete. The only change needed is

```
    With .ShapeRange
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Width = Cells(EmptyRow, 1).Width
    End With
```

> One unit of `column width` is equal to the width of one character in the Normal style.

> `Range.Width`returns a Double value that represents the width of a range in points.

Please refers to Microsoft document.

[Range.ColumnWidth property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.columnwidth?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

[Range.Width property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.width?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

---

> Question: Is there no way to fix the image aspect ratio if the column width or row height is manually changed?

> Answer: The provided code auto-fit image with column width and extend row height as needed. (similar logic as your OP)

```vb
Sub AutoFitImage()
    Dim s As Shape
    For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        s.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        s.Placement = xlFreeFloating
        s.ScaleWidth 1, msoTrue
        s.ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue
        s.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        With s.TopLeftCell
            s.Top = .Top
            s.Left = .Left
            s.Width = .Width
            .EntireRow.RowHeight = s.Height
        End With
        s.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    Next
End Sub
```

If you prefer to shrink image to autofit a cell, please refers to

[In Excel, can a button be created to insert photos into cells without distorting the original image aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76864383/in-excel-can-a-button-be-created-to-insert-photos-into-cells-without-distorting/76864598#76864598)

Comment: That's very useful, thank you very much. The insertion works the way I want now, but there are still issues with the adjustment side of things.

Comment: Do you mind specify what's the issue with adjustment? A screeshot on OP is helpful to understand.

Comment: Actually, what I thought I wanted out of adjustments is not what I actually wanted, because it would cause some inconsistencies in the dimensions of the picture column, so you've solved all my issues. Thanks :)

Comment: Forgive my hastiness to say things are solved. On the widening of the picture column, the image does widen along with the column, but the aspect ratio is not maintained. How may I add a screenshot to the OP?

Comment: Edit your post, press Ctrl+G to load image OR paste image from clipboard

Comment: Thanks, hopefully the edit is clarifies my issue.

Comment: Do you have `.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue` in your revised code? It will keep the image aspect ratio. The image aspect ratio will be changed if you manually adjust the column width or row height.

Comment: Yes, it is still true. Is there no way to fix the image aspect ratio if the column width or row height is manually changed?

Comment: Manually changing column width or row height don't trigger system event.  It's no way to automatically fix it. But you always can run a sub to fix it. The code depends on your auto-fitting logic. I have updated my reply. Hope it's helpful for you.

Comment: I'm guessing I paste the given code into either the worksheet of concern, or in a module, and call it within the code block I originally posted?

Comment: Yes. I'd like to remind you that `AutoFitImage` only fix the image aspect ratio on `ActiveSheet`.