# Make pictures adapt the size of the cells

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a VBA code that go through my folders and puts pictures in cells.
For example in line `A2:A7`, I put some files names inside each cell "test.jpg" or "demo.jpg" and when I launch this code it goes through the given folders and display the pictures I want :

```
Private FileLocations As Collection

Public Sub Test()

    Set FileLocations = New Collection
    GetFiles "C:\Users\usertest\Desktop\demo" 'UPDATE PATH
    
    Dim PicName As Range
    Dim img As Picture
    
    'Work through each image name in range Sheet1!A2:A7.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1") 'UPDATE SHEET NAME.
        For Each PicName In .Range("A2:A7") 'UPDATE RANGE.
            'Place the image within the cell containing the file name.
            Set img = .Pictures.Insert(FileLocations(PicName))
            img.Left = PicName.Left
            img.Top = PicName.Top
            img.Height = PicName.Height
        Next PicName
    End With
    
End Sub
```

```
'Place each path/file name within the FileLocations collection.
Public Sub GetFiles(sPath As String)

    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim fldr As Object
    Set fldr = fso.getfolder(sPath)
    
    Dim subfldr As Object
    Dim myFile As Object
    For Each subfldr In fldr.SubFolders
        For Each myFile In subfldr.Files
            FileLocations.Add subfldr & "\" & myFile.Name, myFile.Name
        Next myFile
    Next subfldr
    
End Sub
```

But my problem is that the pictures doesn't adapt in the size of the cells.
Someone told me to use maybe this `img.Width = PicName.Offset(, 120)` but I don't really understand

I'm just starting in VBA coding so I was wondering if anyone could help me.

I have tried to use this lign `img.Width = PicName.Offset(, 120)` but nothing really work

Comment: Not sure where my original answer for this went - was it on this forum?  The `img.Left`, `img.Top`, etc lines should be resizing the image to the size of the cell, but it keeps the aspect ratio so the width will change depending on the height.  If you add this extra line after the `Set img =` line:  `img.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse` the following image sizing lines will stretch the image to fill the cell, but could distort the image.

Comment: I suggested the `PicName.Offset(, 120)` line as thought you were putting the required image sizes in the cells next to the name (did I put 120?  Should've been 1).  That line would pull the value from the cell 1 (or 120) cells to the right of your image name and use that as the width element of the image size.

Comment: thanks, it does distort the image but it's a start so i will try to improve it. I just have an issue,  here :  "For Each PicName In .Range("A2:A7") 'UPDATE RANGE",  if I let A2:A7 but the next two cells (A8:A9) i put inside files that doesn't exist in my folder and then in A10:A11 i have two mores files that exist there will be a problem and the last two celles won't display the pictures. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76864383/in-excel-can-a-button-be-created-to-insert-photos-into-cells-without-distorting/76864598#76864598

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have updated the code to include stretching the image to cover the cell and added a function that checks if the file name exists in the collection.

```
Private FileLocations As Collection

Public Sub Test()

    Set FileLocations = New Collection
    GetFiles "C:\Users\dbartrup-cook\OneDrive - GrandVision\Documents\Test"
    
    Dim PicName As Range
    Dim img As Picture
    
    'Work through each image name in range Sheet1!A2:A4.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each PicName In .Range("A2:A5")
            'Place the image within the cell containing the file name.
            If ExistsInDictionary(FileLocations, PicName) Then
                Set img = .Pictures.Insert(FileLocations(PicName))
                img.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
                img.Left = PicName.Left
                img.Top = PicName.Top
                img.Width = PicName.Width
                img.Height = PicName.Height
            End If
        Next PicName
    End With
    
End Sub

'Try to set a reference to the collection item.  Failure will throw an error and return False.
Public Function ExistsInDictionary(Target As Collection, Value As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim Tmp As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
        Tmp = Target(Value)
        ExistsInDictionary = (Err.Number = 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

'Place each path/file name within the FileLocations collection.
Public Sub GetFiles(sPath As String)

    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim fldr As Object
    Set fldr = fso.getfolder(sPath)
    
    Dim subfldr As Object
    Dim myFile As Object
    For Each subfldr In fldr.SubFolders
        For Each myFile In subfldr.Files
            FileLocations.Add subfldr & "\" & myFile.Name, myFile.Name
        Next myFile
    Next subfldr
    
End Sub
```