# Macro to insert pictures from a folder down an excel column?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Alright folks, I could use some help trying to create a macro that can insert a slew of pictures down a column in Excel based off of the picture file names down another corresponding column. Im trying to create multiple reports with pictures within a short amount of time, and the only way I think I can pull it off is if I dont have to manually copy and paste the picture of every single item.

I only have this vba so far that printed out the picture of the file name called, but I basically need this exact process to go down the entire rest of the column and pull the picture based off the picture file name down the column:

Here:

```
   Sub InsertPicture()
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture _
Filename:="C:\Users\mrell\Pictures\como.png", _
LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
Left:=ActiveCell.Left, _
Top:=ActiveCell.Top, _
Width:=-1, Height:=-1
End Sub

Sub y()

End Sub
Sub x()

End Sub
```

- The picture pulled but it was huge. Id need it to hopefully be
  wrapped into the cell/within the cell if possible. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhv30.png) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhv30.png)

  Original file, I want to run a vba that will pull the photos and
  insert them down column c, based off of the file names in column b).
  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkA1T.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkA1T.png)

  So basically this would be the final result. A slew of photos would
  be going down column G, preferably within their own boxes [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlOaf.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlOaf.png)

  If possible, Id prefer them to not have lock aspect ratio
  clicked/formatted, and to move and size with the cells? [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MR1G.png) [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MR1G.png)

So does anyone think they can basically, take the insert photo idea from above:

-But have the vba go completely down the column (lets say column C), and enters into column C....the photo that has the file name next door (same row) in Column B?

Could anyone possibly help direct me with this?

Comment: Does the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77307132/make-pictures-adapt-the-size-of-the-cells/77309382#77309382) help?